# Android Studio enum left right bug? How to disable RTL warnings for whole project?

Tags: android, android-studio

Android Studio should be known for those in most cases just aggravating Lint "Using left/right instead of start/end attributes" warnings. I'm using Android Studio 0.8.9, but the following problem was also present in earlier versions: If you add this ultra-minimal snippet anywhere in your code

```
public enum BiteMeLint {
    LEFT
}
```

Android Studio shows the warning

> Use "Gravity.START" instead of "Gravity.LEFT" to ensure correct behavior in right-to-left locales.

This also happens for the constant RIGHT, though it suggests to use Gravity.END in that case. Now I'm a developer who likes to keep his code completely clean of any warnings, either by complying or, if that's not possible, by suppressing and putting a "todo" or "fixme" where necessary. Here, since I'm using "LEFT" and "RIGHT" as constants for actual directions, the warning is obviously a bug. Sadly, adding

```
@SuppressLint("RtlHardcoded")
```

doesn't remove the warning. So how do I remove this joke of a warning? And now that I'm asking, can I somehow completely disable RTL warnings for a project I'm sure will never launch in a right-to-left locale?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to [this issue tracker](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=75480), it is a bug which was fixed in Android Studio 0.8.10 recently.

The option to disable this inspection can be found under `Project Settings | Inspections | Android Lint | Unsing left/right instead of start/end attributes`. So you can simply disable it for the whole project by unchecking the box.

Comment: Really? Now it's fixed? That means waiting for the next beta-version will solve that, thanks. Any idea how to disable RTL warnings for a specific project, though?

Answer (score 4):

### Android Studio 3

Go to **File > Settings > Editor > Inspections > Android > Lint > Internationalization > Bidirectional Text**.

Then uncheck *Using left/right instead of start/end* attributes.

### But...

You may not want to actually disable the warning. It is there for a reason. Read what the Android Studio description says about it:

> Using Gravity#LEFT
> and Gravity#RIGHT can lead to problems when a layout is rendered in
> locales where text flows from right to left. Use Gravity#START and
> Gravity#END instead. Similarly, in XML gravity and layout_gravity
> attributes, use start rather than left.
>
> For XML attributes such as
> paddingLeft and layout_marginLeft, use paddingStart and
> layout_marginStart. NOTE: If your minSdkVersion is less than 17, you
> should add both the older left/right attributes as well as the new
> start/right attributes. On older platforms, where RTL is not supported
> and the start/right attributes are unknown and therefore ignored, you
> need the older left/right attributes. There is a separate lint check
> which catches that type of error.
>
> (Note: For Gravity#LEFT and
> Gravity#START, you can use these constants even when targeting older
> platforms, because the start bitmask is a superset of the left
> bitmask. Therefore, you can use gravity="start" rather than
> gravity="left|start".)

Answer (score 0):

In the manifest, disabling the android:supportsRtl attribute will disable the Rtl lint warnings for the whole module

```
      android:supportsRtl="false"
```